# How to edit manifest on android studio 1.4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

guys. I hope you have a great day, today :)

Firstly, I have installed new version of android studio 1.4.1 today. After that, I try to make new project. And then, I try to add new activity on my manifest file. Finally, I run my project, after that my manifest file cannot save last modification I've made. Just return to default setting of manifest file.
What I've to do to adding new activity in my manifest file?
May I to do a wrong step or something?

Thank you for your help :)
Best Regards, sand

Comment: You manually add activities to the manifest? I thought they were added automatically when you make a new activity through the UI. I only manually modify the manifest when things get messed up with my project.

Comment: Yes, I adding manually, because after I made new activity, I saw my manifest file didn't have the new thing of that. So, I put the activity manually.

Comment: My problem have solved. My mistake is, I has edited the wrong file manifest. I has edited file manifest on app/build/intermediate/manifest/AndroidManifest.xml. The true file for adding new activity on the manifest is from directory app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml. So for your information, Android Studio 1.4.1 have a good capability for diretoring file, and can help you a lof of fun. Keep rock and roll for coding guys. Tq for your help, and just only see my question, this is make me burning up :)